# How to add a row cell value based on other rows cell values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like below

| Id | Date | Aid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-01 | one |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | two |
| 2 | 2022-01-05 | one |
| 3 | 2022-01-06 | three |
| 4 | 2022-01-02 | one |
| 5 | 2022-01-01 | one |

I would like to add a column "counter" which, for each row, will contain the number of rows with the same "Aid" and "Date" lower or equal with the row's "Date"

So, for row 4, 'Counter' = 3 (rows 0, 4, 5).

The result should be:

| Id | Date | Aid | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-01 | one | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | two | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-05 | one | 4 |
| 3 | 2022-01-06 | three | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-01-02 | one | 3 |
| 5 | 2022-01-01 | one | 2 |

Is there a way to do this count in pandas ?

The original dataframe contains milions of rows so efficiency is very important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rank` with max method

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).groupby(df['Aid']).rank(method='max').astype('int')
```

output:

```
0    2
1    1
2    4
3    1
4    3
5    2
Name: Date, dtype: int32
```

make output to Counter column

```
df.assign(Counter=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).groupby(df['Aid']).rank(method='max').astype('int'))
```

result:

```
Id  Date        Aid     Counter
0   2022-01-01  one     2
1   2022-01-01  two     1
2   2022-01-05  one     4
3   2022-01-06  three   1
4   2022-01-02  one     3
5   2022-01-01  one     2
```